# A Question Regarding the Relationship between God and Messiah

Tags: old-testament, messiah

As for the Messiah, of him God says,

> And I will set up one shepherd over them, and he shall feed them,
>   even My servant David; he shall feed them, and he shall be their
>   shepherd. And I the Lord will be their God, and My servant David
>   prince among them; I the Lord have spoken. (Ezekiel 34:23-24)

In a related passage ...

> The kings of the earth set themselves, And the rulers take counsel
>   together, Against the Lord and against His Anointed. (Psalm 2:2)

As indicated by the first verse, The Lord alone will be worshiped as God, while the Messiah, as the servant of God, lives with the people.

As indicated by the second verse, the Lord and the Messiah are mutually exclusive, and not the same being.

How is this apparent contradiction explained in the light of New Testament allusions to the Messiah's divinity?

Comment: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690/23657.   Your question is going to need a little work to be a good fit for this site have a look at the link to see how you might be able to scope it to work here.

Comment: As you noticed, the Scriptures do indicate the Messiah is a servant of God. Here is some Bible study information that helps put this into perspective by answering such questions as: What do the words “Messiah” and “Christ” mean? What does the Bible teach about Jesus’ life before he came to earth? Why does the Bible say that Jesus is “the image of the invisible God”?  https://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/bible-study/who-is-jesus-christ/

Comment: Can you please [edit] this to explain more clearly how you get the idea of God alone being worshipped from Ezekiel 34:23-24? I can't see anything there saying that.

Comment: Are you looking for a trinitarian perspective, or a non-trinitarian perspective?  The issue of "persons" of the trinity will figure into such an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Dan 7:14 we see the Son of Man is coming to take the everlasting kingdom. In the subsequent verses termed as the interpretation we see in verse 22 it is the Ancient of Days who is coming. This tells me the ancient of days and the Son of Man are the same.

In traditional Judaism, they have a picture of G-d as a composite of potencies called sephirot. Different combinations can form different faces of G-d. They are all divine and are none are independent of each other yet we have examples in their literature where one speaks to another. Not all are credited with creation. Pro 3:19  The LORD by **wisdom** hath founded the earth; by **understanding** hath he established the heavens. 1Co_1:24 tells us this wisdom is Messiah. We have an entire proverb (8) which deals with wisdom and alludes to its deity and power to save. It also states it (wisdom) is understanding, alluding to their combination in creation (v 19).

When we impose on G-d the limitations of a physical world (where something has one nature, one presence, one spacial dimension, etc.) we are always going to have a difficulty.

But even in nature we have examples of duality. An amoeba can change shape and when it reproduces by meiosis, one cannot say that this part is the parent and that part is the child, they are both identical even though they occupy different places in space.

Comment: The Son of Man isn't the Ancient of Days, because Daniel 7:13 says the Son of Man comes to the Ancient of Days. This answer doesn't seem to address the scriptures in the question.

Answer (score -2):

Daniel 7:13

“In my vision at night I looked, and there before me was one like a son of man,[a]coming with the clouds of heaven. He approached the Ancient of Days and was led into his presence. **14 He was given authority,glory and sovereign power; all nations and peoples of every language worshiped him.** His dominion is an everlasting dominion that will not pass away, and his kingdom is one that will never be destroyed.

[a]Daniel 7:13 The Aramaic phrase *bar enash* means human being.

Note the term **worshipped**

I am assuming that the question is to clarify the allusion by new testament writers on why the Messiah is both divine and human.

- Only God is worthy of worship
- We see a human being worshipped and given dominion over all, in Daniel's Vision

  - Therefore this being is both God and Man at the same time. Duality of Divinity.
- The reason for this elevation is visible through a careful study of the implicit prophecies in the old testament fulfilled explicitly in the new testament.
- List of prophecies [need assistance with hermeneutics while studying the same](http://www.accordingtothescriptures.org/prophecy/353prophecies.html)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how your argument works. Can you please [edit] this to explain in more detail?

Comment: Out of [51 translations](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Daniel%207:14), only 4 use the word "worship" in Daniel 7:14. One says "obey," and the other 46 translations say "serve".

Comment: Note the root word *Pe`al* , Aramaic, pay reverence to deity: Note also the use of another word *Abad* which means to serve used in Joshua 24:15 - choose for yourselves this day whom you will **serve**, whether the gods your ancestors **served** beyond the Euphrates, or the gods of the Amorites, in whose land you are living. But as for me and my household,we will **serve the Lord**.” The context for *serve* is a diety in both cases.

Comment: @user39729 Daniel 3:28 uses the exact same word used in Daniel 7:14. From that verse it's clear that "worship" isn't a good translation for it, and that it refers to a lesser form of activity than worship. Hebrew argument aside, I don't see how this answer addresses how Ezekiel 34:24 says the Messiah is God's "servant," and not God himself.

Comment: @4castle the question wasn't if the Messiah was God's servant or not. It was to understand a contraction in the duality of being while figuring the *being* at the receiving end of worship. I have quoted Daniel illustrating how that *being* would have an everlasting dominion. There is none who can have anything everlasting but God. Everlasting meaning end to end. *I am the beginning and the end Isa 44:6*

Comment: @user39729 The question is about reconciling the supposed contradiction between Ezekiel 34:24, and the claim that the Messiah is God. The question makes the observation that Ezekiel 34:24 presents the Messiah as mutually exclusive to God, and your answer doesn't address that. Right now, your answer appears to just ignore Ezekiel.

Comment: @4castle Ezekiel 34 speaks of one shepherd, the Sovereign Lord, the same one Isaiah speaks about when he says, ‘See, the Sovereign Lord *Comes* with power, and his arm rules for him…. He tends his flock like a shepherd: he gathers the lambs in his arms and carries them close to his heart;  (Isa. 40:10, 11).

Comment: @user39729 Ezekiel 34 describes how the role of "one shepherd" is delegated to "My servant David." In the context of that verse, it doesn't say the shepherd is the Sovereign Lord, even though some other verse may also describe God as a shepherd. (By the way, answering the question should be done by editing your answer. We don't want the answer to just be in the comments)

Comment: Do you feel that with the edits you have shown that there isn't a contradiction?  You may need to summarize a few more points from your link ...